# MYSQL selecting across multiple tables + using mathematical operators Average/Count

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables with the following attributes:

Table: Department

dept_nbr

dept_name

dept_phone

dept_building

dept_mgr

Table: Employee

emp_nbr

emp_lname

emp_fname

emp_phone

emp_dateofbirth

emp_date_hired

emp_nbr_of_dependents

emp_dept

**dept_nbr = emp_dept**

I need:

**for each dept**

1.) total no. of employee dependents

2.) average no. of dependents. - i am guessing AVG

3.) total no. of employees - i am guessing count(*)

Could someone please help me counter this?following is my code

```
  select DEPT_NAME, AVG(EMP_NBR_OF_DEPENDENTs), count(emp_fname) as Total_No_of_Employees from dept,employee where DEPT_NBR = EMP_DEPT group by DEPT_NAME;
```

second part:

include those departments that have fewer than 50 employees

```
select DEPT_NAME, AVG(EMP_NBR_OF_DEPENDENTs), count(emp_fname) as Total_No_of_Employees from dept,employee where DEPT_NBR in (select EMP_DEPT from employee where count(emp_fname)<50) group by DEPT_NAME ;
```

i tried the above and got an error 1111

Thanks Heaps

Comment: What you have tried as you guessed have you applied anything

Comment: Did you even try to solve the issues you are faced with or do you want us to code the program for you?

Comment: I have added what i've tried so far. It gives me the output..but i don't know if its accurate/best way to do it. Thanks for checking out the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT dept_name,SUM(emp_nbr_of_dependents),AVG(emp_nbr_of_dependents),COUNT(emp_nbr) 
FROM deptartment JOIN employee ON dept_nbr=emp_dept
GROUP BY dept_name
HAVING COUNT(emp_nbr)<50
```

Comment: Thank you..is there any other way by not using HAVING?

Comment: Maybe there is other way with nested select but why you'd like to avoid HAVING? That's perfect regular SQL syntax.

Answer (score 0):

More aggregation functions can be combined in one select.

```
select DEPT_NAME, 
  sum(EMP_NBR_OF_DEPENDENTs) employee_dependents_sum,
  AVG(EMP_NBR_OF_DEPENDENTs) avg_nbr_dependents, 
  count(emp_nbr) employee_count
from dept,employee 
where DEPT_NBR = EMP_DEPT 
group by DEPT_NAME
having employee_count < 50;
```

`WHERE` part is applied before `GROUP BY` and then `HAVING` is applied on result.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html

Comment: Thanks..i knew there was a more efficient way of doing it. The results are same but this seems like a better way. Any suggestions for the second part..my where statement didn't work.

Comment: Edited answer to contain second part.